# How to cache video in react native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

How to cache video in react native? I'm trying to cache the video and then play that cached video in React Native using the bare react native project but installed expo-av can anyone please help me to do that? Also currently using react-native-fs, and getting a URL like this /Users/jamess/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/6B345354-6F3456-4534535A-5353454-9814353456F/data/Containers/Data/Application/D34535D5-E7A5-4F35354F-B42342B-7223424535352/Documents/video5_g243f4.mp4. but its not working

Also it just work fine on react-native-video but what's wrong with expo-av?

```
const App = (props: Props) => {
    const [video, setVideo] = useState('');

    useEffect(() => {
        downloadVideo(props.video);
    }, []);

    const downloadVideo = async (videoUrl) => {
        const filename = videoUrl.substring(videoUrl.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
        const cachePath = RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath
        const exists = await RNFS.exists(cachePath + filename);
        if (!exists) {
            const data = await fetch(videoUrl);
            const blob = await data.blob();
            await RNFS.writeFile(cachePath + filename, blob);
        }
        console.log(`${cachePath}/${filename}`)
        setVideo(`${cachePath}/${filename}`)
    };


    console.log(props.video)
    return (
        <View>
            <Video
               source={{uri: video}}
                resizeMode="cover"
                repeat
                shouldPlay
                isMuted={false}
                style={styles.backgroundVideo}
            />
        </View>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the server side you could set it up with an eTag, then store the eTag ( instead of the video ) and send If-None-Match header so that server compares the eTags and sends back 304 unmodified instead of 200 ok.

See [here](https://github.com/encode/starlette/blob/74ccb961b3c1b1871aa7ed70a81dd3000e0194da/starlette/responses.py#L322) for etag generation:
and [here](https://github.com/encode/starlette/blob/74ccb961b3c1b1871aa7ed70a81dd3000e0194da/starlette/staticfiles.py#L188) for checking: